# Why the mention of Mabul water level in relation to mountains, who could testify it?

Tags: parashat-noach, mabul

The Torah describes that in the mabul (flood), the tops of the mountains were covered and also that the tops of the mountains were visible when the flood receded.

> When the waters had swelled much more upon the earth, all the highest mountains everywhere under the sky were covered.
>
> Fifteen cubits higher did the waters swell, as the mountains were
> covered. [(Bereishis 7:19-20)](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.7.20)

> The waters went on diminishing until the tenth month; in the tenth month, on the first of the month, the tops of the mountains became visible. [(Bereishis 8:5)](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.7.20)

Who could testify to these situations? Because the entire generation of the flood did not survive and Noah was in the ark and if he had opened the door would his ark have been flooded.

And also that he didn't have the leisure to watch the beam outside since he had to feed all the animals throughout the day.

Comment: Who could testify that Hashem made Chava from Adam's side? Only Hashem, through Moshe Rabbeinu. What's the purpose of your question?

Comment: Who could testify what Hashem created in the six days of creation?

Comment: Maybe Og while he hung to the side of the ark.

Comment: Moreover, in the case of Chava, there was Adam to testify. In the case of the Mabul, the mountains were indication for the status of the flood. How could Noah know when to send the pigeon? In addition, Noah could not estimate the level of the flood on earth (that's why he sent the pigeon) , but the level of flood on mountain is mentioned clearly.

Comment: @Avi what about the six days of creation? Torah is not reliant on humans being able to testify that each statement occurred. It's just irrelevant.

Comment: @Esther, in the sixth days of creation the human were not involved at all. In the case of Noah, I think there is an inner reason for the Torah to mention twice the level of the flood in the mountains. In addition, it is interesting what was the indication for Noah to send the pigeon at the specific time? Does it relate to the flood level on the mountains?

Comment: @Avi so your question is "why the mention of water level," not "who could testify," is that right? You might want to edit your question so you get more targeted and useful answers.

Comment: @Esther, thanks for your comment. I think that the both relates one to another. Anyway. I'll try to edit my question.

Comment: What Esther is saying is correct. Jewish tradition says that the Torah itself preceded the Creation by 2000 years. That means all that is written in the Torah that we learn today preceded and existed prior to actual creation. From our perspective, that is a time paradox. But since G-d and Torah are one, the constraints of linear time (or otherwise) do not apply.

Answer (score 6):

> Who could testify to these situations?

Your question deals with one of the "ikkarim" of our faith. One of the principles of the Jewish faith. What is it? Well, the Rambam (Maimonides) says that we need to believe in the divine origin of the Torah and that G-d gave it to us. Refer to [his introduction to perek Cheilek](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/332555/jewish/Maimonides-13-Principles-of-Faith.htm).

Also, refer to the famous introduction of the Ramban (Nachmanides) on the Torah. He [says](https://www.sefaria.org/Ramban_on_Genesis,_Foreword.1):

> משה רבנו כתב הספר הזה עם התורה כולה מפיו של הקב"ה. והקרוב שכתב זה בהר סיני, כי שם נאמר לו: "עלה אלי ההרה והיה שם, ואתנה לך את לוחות האבן והתורה והמצוה אשר כתבתי להורותם". כי 'לוחות האבן' – יכלול הלוחות והמכתב, כלומר עשרת הדברות, ו'המצוה' – מספר המצות כולן, עשה ולא תעשה. אם כן, 'והתורה' – יכלול הספורים מתחילת בראשית, כי הוא מורה אנשים בדרך בענין האמונה.
> Moses our teacher wrote this book of Genesis together with the whole Torah from the mouth of the Holy One, blessed be He. It is likely that he wrote it on Mount Sinai for there it was said to him, Come up to Me unto the mount, and be there; and I will give thee the tablets of stone and the Torah and the commandment which I have written, to teach them. The tablets of stone include the tablets and the writing that are the ten commandments. The commandment includes the number of all the commandments, positive and negative. If so, the expression and the Torah includes the stories from the beginning of Genesis [and is called Torah — teaching] because it teaches people the ways of faith.

So, to summarize, how do we know that the mountains were covered with the water? Well, simply put, because G-d told Moshe that it happened, and we must believe that this is the divine truth.